# First order filters in Direct Form I (RBJ Cookbook)

Tags: filters, lowpass-filter, biquad

I've implemented second order biquad filters using the famous [RBJ Cookbook](https://webaudio.github.io/Audio-EQ-Cookbook/audio-eq-cookbook.html). I also want to implement first order lowpass and highpass filters. I was hoping to use the same code, so I need to define these first order filters in Direct Form I.

I found [examples](https://www.earlevel.com/main/2021/09/02/biquad-calculator-v3/) of first order filters in Direct Form II, but nothing for Direct Form I. I tried fudging the Direct Form II coefficients into Direct Form I, but I can't get it right.

What would be the correct way to calculating the coefficients? Thank you!

**EDIT:** I tried converting the Direct Form II filters to Direct Form I, but this makes them hard to automate because a0 is hardcoded to 1:

```
const K = Math.tan(Math.PI * freq / sampleRate);
const norm = 1 / (1 / K + 1);
b0 = norm;
b1 = norm;
b2 = 0;
a0 = 1;
a1 = (1 - 1 / K) * norm;
a2 = 0;
```

Is there a way to convert this filter (listed as first order lowpass in [Biquad Calculator v3](https://www.earlevel.com/main/2021/09/02/biquad-calculator-v3/)) to a standard Direct Form I filter?

Comment: You can use first-order filters only for LPF (and Low Shelf), HPF (and High Shelf), and APF.  They're not hard to design, there are only 3 coefficients and two degrees of freedom to worry about (excluding overall gain) or one for APF.  Sorry I didn't bother to include these designs.  I also didn't include the Orfanidis variation of the Peaking EQ either.

Comment: First get the analog prototypes with normalized $s$ for these first-order buggers.  Then use the same Bilinear Transform: $$ \text{(normalized)   } \qquad s \leftarrow \frac{1}{\tan \frac{\omega_0}{2}} \frac{1-z^{-1}}{1+z^{-1}}$$

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I've tried using the bilinear transform, but it's a bit too hard for me to understand as I don't come from an engineering background. I found out how to translate the Direct Form II filters, but since a0 is hardcoded to 1 they can't be automated cleanly like the original filters

Comment: LPF1: `H(s) = 1 / (1 + s/w0)` --> `num = 1`, `den = [1 w0]`. HPF1: `H(s) = s/w0 / (1 + s/w0)` --> `num = [w0 0]` and `den = [1 w0]`. `w0 = 2*pi*f `.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I'm gonna try to toss out here my first guess of general 1st-order filters done in the style of the [Audio EQ Cookbook](https://www.w3.org/TR/audio-eq-cookbook/).  The cookbook assumes the same EE definition of resonant frequency and normalizes that parameter out of $s$ in the analog transfer functions and then uses this version of the Bilinear Transform with prewarping:

$$ \text{(normalized)} \qquad s \leftarrow \frac{1}{\tan \frac{\omega_0}{2}} \times \frac{1-z^{-1}}{1+z^{-1}} = \frac{1+\cos(\omega_0)}{\sin(\omega_0)} \times \frac{1-z^{-1}}{1+z^{-1}} $$

where

$$ \omega_0 \triangleq 2 \pi \frac{f_0}{F_\mathrm{s}} $$

and $f_0$ is the *"significant frequency"*, which is the -3 dB frequency for LPF and HPF and the shelf-midpoint frequency for the shelf filters (which is how the Cookbook defines it for its 2nd-order shelf filters).  $F_\mathrm{s}$ is the sample rate.

For the shelf filters

$$ A \triangleq \sqrt{10^{dB_\mathrm{gain}/20}} = 10^{dB_\mathrm{gain}/40} $$

The $z$-plane transfer function is:

$$\begin{align}
 H(z) &= \frac{b_0 + b_1 z^{-1}}{a_0 + a_1 z^{-1}} \\
\\
 &= \frac{\frac{b_0}{a_0} + \frac{b_1}{a_0} z^{-1}}{1 + \frac{a_1}{a_0} z^{-1}} \\
\end{align}$$

The Direct I Form implementation is:

$$ y[n] =  \tfrac{b_0}{a_0} x[n] + \tfrac{b_1}{a_0} x[n-1] - \tfrac{a_1}{a_0} y[n-1]$$

---

**LPF**

$$ H(s) = \frac{1}{1+s} $$

$$\begin{align}
a_0 &= \sin(\omega_0) + 1 + \cos(\omega_0) \\
a_1 &= \sin(\omega_0) - 1 - \cos(\omega_0)\\
b_0 &= \sin(\omega_0) \\
b_1 &= \sin(\omega_0) \\
\end{align}$$

**HPF**

$$ H(s) = \frac{s}{1+s} $$

$$\begin{align}
a_0 &= \sin(\omega_0) + 1 + \cos(\omega_0) \\
a_1 &= \sin(\omega_0) - 1 - \cos(\omega_0)\\
b_0 &= 1 + \cos(\omega_0) \\
b_1 &= -1 - \cos(\omega_0) \\
\end{align}$$

**APF**

$$ H(s) = \frac{1-s}{1+s} $$

$$\begin{align}
a_0 &= \sin(\omega_0) + 1 + \cos(\omega_0) \\
a_1 &= \sin(\omega_0) - 1 - \cos(\omega_0) \\
b_0 &= \sin(\omega_0) - 1 - \cos(\omega_0) \\
b_1 &= \sin(\omega_0) + 1 + \cos(\omega_0) \\
\end{align}$$

**LowShelf**

$$ H(s) = \frac{A+s}{\frac{1}{A}+s} $$

$$\begin{align}
a_0 &= \tfrac{1}{A}\sin(\omega_0) + 1 + \cos(\omega_0) \\
a_1 &= \tfrac{1}{A}\sin(\omega_0) - 1 - \cos(\omega_0) \\
b_0 &= A\sin(\omega_0) + 1 + \cos(\omega_0) \\
b_1 &= A\sin(\omega_0) - 1 - \cos(\omega_0) \\
\end{align}$$

**HighShelf**

$$ H(s) = \frac{1+As}{1+\frac{s}{A}} $$

$$\begin{align}
a_0 &= \sin(\omega_0) + A + A\cos(\omega_0) \\
a_1 &= \sin(\omega_0) - A - A\cos(\omega_0) \\
b_0 &= \sin(\omega_0) + \tfrac{1}{A} + \tfrac{1}{A}\cos(\omega_0) \\
b_1 &= \sin(\omega_0) - \tfrac{1}{A} - \tfrac{1}{A}\cos(\omega_0) \\
\end{align}$$

This maybe should get added to the Cookbook.  I guess I never really thought of doing that.  Ain't that weird?

Answer (score 3):

A solution with the DC or Nyquist bin zeroed for a high pass or low pass respectively with real coefficients is:

**LOW PASS**

$b_0 = \frac{1+a_1}{2}$ 
$b_1 = b_0$
$b_2 = 0$
$a_0 =  1$
$a_1 =  -\frac{\cos(\omega_c)}{\sin(\omega_c)+1}$
$a_2 = 0$

**HIGH PASS**

$b_0 = \frac{1-a_1}{2}$ 
$b_1 = -b_0$
$b_2 = 0$
$a_0 =  1$
$a_1 =  -\frac{\cos(\omega_c)}{\sin(\omega_c)+1}$
$a_2 = 0$

Where $\omega_c$ is the cutoff frequency as the normalized radian frequency in units of radians/sample. For a sampling frequency in Hz as $f_s$ and cutoff frequency in Hz as $f$, the cutoff frequency in normalied radian units is given as:

$$\omega_c = \frac{2\pi f}{f_s}$$

For the above block diagrams, $a_0$ not shown explicitly is normalized such that $a_0=1$.

Validating this, I tested with $\omega_c=\pi/4$ and $\omega_c=3\pi/4$ using the functions in Octave as (and plotted the magnitude responses by passing `num` and `den` into `freqz`):

```
function [num, den] = lowpass(omega)
  a0 = 1;
  a1 = -cos(omega)/(sin(omega)+1);
  b0= (1+a1)/2;
  b1 = b0;
  num = [b0 b1];
  den = [a0 a1];
endfunction

function [num, den] = highpass(omega)
  a0 = 1;
  a1 = -cos(omega)/(sin(omega)+1);
  b0= (1-a1)/2;
  b1 = -b0;
  num = [b0 b1];
  den = [a0 a1];
endfunction
```

[image: magnitude response]

The coefficients don't change between Direct Form I and Direct Form II: Direct Form II is simply Direct Form I with the two sections reordered:

[image: Direct Form I]

[image: Direct Form I reordered]

[image: Direct Form II]

**DETAILS / DERIVATION**

The OP had originally posted the question using $a1=0$ and $a2=0$. This would have been a simple first order FIR filters given as:

$$H(z) = K(1 - b_1z^{-1})$$

Where $K$ is a scaling constant for unity gain. If we assume real coefficients only, then for $b_1>0$ we get a low pass response, and for $b_1<0$ we get a high pass response with a single real zero at $z=b_1$ and a trivial pole at the origin $z=0$. This structure is of limited use since the dynamic range between the frequency at $\omega=0$ (DC) and $\omega = \pi$ ($f_s/2$ where $f_s$ is the sampling rate) will diminish rapidly as the zero moves away from $z=1$ or $z=-1$.

A more useful but still first order filter, as an IIR filter would be given as:

$$H(z) = K\frac{1+b_1z^{-1}}{1+a_1z^{-1}}$$

For this case, the filter has a single zero at $z=-b_1$ and pole at $z=-a_1$. For the low-pass case, set the zero to be $z=-1$ placing a frequency response null at Nyquist resulting in $b_1=1$. For the high-pass case, set the zero to be $z=1$ placing a frequency response null at DC and resulting in $b_1=-1$. We can set the bandwidth as a function of the pole placement in each case as follows:

**LOW PASS FILTER**

$$H(z) = K\frac{1+z^{-1}}{1+a_1z^{-1}}= K\frac{z+1}{z+a_1}$$

Set $K$ to normalize gain = 1 at DC ($z=1$):

$$H(z) = \bigg(\frac{1+a_1}{2}\bigg)\frac{z+1}{z+a_1}\label{1}\tag{1}$$

The squared magnitude response is given as:

$$|H(e^{j\omega})|^2 = H(e^{j\omega})H(e^{-j\omega}) $$

$$= \bigg(\frac{1+a_1}{2}\bigg)^2\bigg(\frac{e^{j\omega}+1}{e^{j\omega}+a_1}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{e^{-j\omega}+1}{e^{-j\omega}+a_1}\bigg) =\bigg(\frac{1+a_1}{2}\bigg)^2\frac{2+2\cos(\omega)}{1+2a_1\cos(\omega)+a_1^2}\label{2}\tag{2}$$

The -3 dB cutoff frequency $\omega_c$ is where the magnitude squared goes to 1/2 power:

$$|H(e^{j\omega_c})|^2 = \bigg(\frac{1+a_1}{2}\bigg)^2\frac{2+2\cos(\omega_c)}{1+2a_1\cos(\omega_c)+a_1^2} = 1/2 \label{3}\tag{3}$$

Solving \ref{3} for $\omega_c$ as a function of real $a_1$, we get:

$$\omega_c = \cos^{-1}\bigg(\frac{ -2a_1}{a_1^2+1}  \bigg)\label{4}\tag{4}$$

Rearranging \ref{4} to solve for $a_1$ as a function of $\omega_c$:

$$a_1 = -\frac{\cos(\omega)}{\sqrt{\sin^2(\omega)}+1}\label{5}\tag{5}$$

Since $0<\omega<\pi$, ref{5} reduces further to be:

$$a_1 = -\frac{\cos(\omega)}{\sin(\omega)+1}\label{6}\tag{6}$$

**HIGH PASS FILTER**

Similarly solving for the case of the High Pass Filter, where:

$$H(z) = \bigg(\frac{1-a_1}{2}\bigg)\frac{z-1}{z+a_1}\label{7}\tag{7}$$

$$|H(e^{j\omega_c})|^2 = \bigg(\frac{1-a_1}{2}\bigg)^2\frac{2-2\cos(\omega_c)}{1+2a_1\cos(\omega_c)+a_1^2} = 1/2 \label{8}\tag{8}$$

Which results in the same relationship for $a_1$ and $\omega_c$ as the Low Pass case.

---

Comment: Thank you! I noticed something seems different with these coefficients, I think a1 should be negative. If I set a1 = -a1 or set a0 = -1 it gives the same coefficients as my original code, which seems to produce the correct frequency response.

Comment: @MysteryPancake, Ah good catch, thank you! I am finding other mistakes from my late night attempts at math...fixing now and will verify.

Comment: When swapping the sign of a1, b0 also gets affected. It seems correct previously, so I used a plus instead of a minus: b0 = (1 + a1) / 2. Vice versa for the highpass

Comment: I got other fish to fry at the moment (Easter), but you should do the first-order recursive APF and then low-shelf and high-shelf.

Comment: Happy Easter @robertbristow-johnson !! I will be frying my own fish very soon.

Comment: Fish? It's chocolate in my house. Rabbits for preference. :-)